# AWS Cloudwatch Metrics showing different number of current connections than redis-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-cloudwatch, redis-cli, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

When I look at the Cloudwatch metrics for a redis cache it reports that there are 3 current connections. When I use the CLIENT LIST command through redis-cli the only connection it reports is the ec2 instance that I am using redis-cli from.

I couldn't find any information about how Cloudwatch gets its current connections info. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/CacheMetrics.Redis.html

The number of client connections, excluding connections from read replicas. ElastiCache uses two to three of the connections to monitor the cluster in each case. This is derived from the connected_clients statistic at Redis INFO.

Comment: Was coming here to suggest exactly this: are you confident that the # of clients == the # of connections? It seems you found the answer is "no"